# How to insert data in oracle database in a cycle from python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, spyder

Good evening!

I have mistake here:

> File "E:\scripts\trytoconnecttoOracledb.py", line 79, in
> connect_to_oracle_database
> cursor.execute(sql_insert)
>
> TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

I want to insert data dynamicaly and see my table filled with generated data

My code is:

And it works with a commented line, but when I try to do it dynamicaly, so I have troubles

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
from datetime import date 
import pandas as pd


def connect_to_oracle_database(delta, d0):
    
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('anton_gridushko/anton_gridushko@xe')
    print(connection.version)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    # creatnion part:
    creation_parameters = ("DIM_DATES", "DATE_ID", "DAY_IN_WEEK_NUMBER", "DAY_IN_MONTH_NUMBER", "DAY_NAME", "WEEKDAY_FLAG", "WEEK_IN_YEAR_NUMBER", "MONTH_IN_YEAR_NUMBER", "MONTH_NAME", "QUARTER_NUMBER", "YEAR_NUMBER")
    statement = """
    CREATE TABLE %s(
        %s DATE NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL,
        %s VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
        %s VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL,
        %s VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL,
        %s NUMBER NOT NULL
        )
    """% creation_parameters
    
    cursor.execute(statement)
    print("Table created")
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # statement = 'INNSERT INTO DIM_DATES(DATE_ID, DAY_IN_WEEK_NUMBER, DAY_IN_MONTH_NUMBER, DAY_NAME, WEEKDAY_FLAG, WEEK_IN_YEAR_NUMBER, MONTH_IN_YEAR_NUMBER, MONTH_NAME, QUARTER_NUMBER, YEAR_NUMBER) VALUES (:2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11)'
    # cursor.execute(statement, (1,3,11,2,4,20,5,3,2,1960))
    
    date = d0
    for i in range(delta.days):
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        
        # date_id = datetime(date.strftime("%d %b %Y"))
        date_id = date
        dinweeknum = int(date.weekday())
        dinmonthnumber = int(date.strftime("%d"))
        dayname = date.strftime("%A")    
        weekno = int(date.weekday())   
        if (weekno < 5): dayflag = "Weekday" 
        else: 
            dayflag = "Weekend"        
        wnum = int(date.isocalendar()[1])
        mnum = int(date.strftime("%m"))
        mname = date.strftime("%B")
        quarter = int(pd.Timestamp(date).quarter)
        yeardate = int(date.strftime("%Y"))
        
        # cursor.execute("INSERT INTO word VALUES (?, ?)", (var1, var2))
        
        # var1 = date_id
        # var2 = dinweeknum + 1
        # var3 = dinmonthnumber
        # var4 = dayname
        # var5 = dayflag
        # var6 = wnum
        # var7 = mnum
        # var8 = mname
        # var9 = quartere
        # var10 = yeardate
        
        
        sql_insert = """INSERT INTO DIM_DATES VALUES (TO_DATE('2001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1, 1, 'Aaa', 'Bbb', 1, 1, 'Ccc', 2, ?)""", dinweeknum
        
        # sql_insert = """INSERT INTO DIM_DATES VALUES (f'TO_DATE('{date_id}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), {dinweeknum + 1}, {dinmonthnumber}, {dayname}, {dayflag}, {wnum}, {mnum}, {mname}, {quarter}, {yeardate}')"""
        
        # sql_insert = """
        #                INSERT INTO DIM_DATES VALUES (TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        #                """, (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10)
                       
        cursor.execute(sql_insert)
        
    connection.commit()   
    # dispose part:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

#Main area
d1 = date(2030, 12, 31)
d0 = date(1969, 12, 31)
delta = d1 - d0

connect_to_oracle_database(delta, d0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are talking about (you have many commented lines but don't say what they each do). If you are asking about binding, then use Oracle's bind syntax, which is shown in cx_Oracle examples like [BindInsert.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py).  That example also shows using `executemany()`, which is very efficient way of inserting multiple data rows.

One example is:

```
dataToInsert = [
    (10, 'Parent 10'),
    (20, 'Parent 20'),
    (30, 'Parent 30'),
    (40, 'Parent 40'),
    (50, 'Parent 50')
]
cursor.executemany("insert into ParentTable values (:1, :2)", dataToInsert)
```

You should avoid looping over a single `execute()` since this will be much slower.

Review the cx_Oracle documentation [Using Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) and [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).